# Mostrar quando não tem resultado da busca no banco de dados

Tags: mysql, algoritmo-de-busca

Na busca SQL, se não retornar resultado é para aparecer uma mensagem "Nenhum resultado encontrado". OK, quando busca, acha um resultado e quando não tem ele mostra a mensagem - até aqui tudo certo. O problema é que na hora de abrir o documento, o texto "Nenhum resultado encontrado" já está lá sendo que eu nem pesquisei nada. Como tiro esse texto sem que altere o comando de ele aparecer quando não tem resultados no BD?

Tentei com Javascript usado `style show/none` com função no `onClick` do *submit* do botão de busca e não adiantou, no retorno de busca sem resultados a mensagem piscava e sumia.

To usando assim:

```
<?php if ($totalRows_buscar == 0) {  ?>
  <?php print "Nenhum resultado encontrado."; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: É necessário você colocar o código completo, para darmos uma resposta concreta.

Comment: São 950 linhas, muito extenso pra colar tudo

Comment: Se o código é muito grande, tente reduzi-lo para um [mcve] <-- leia este link, tem várias dicas para reduzir o seu código para postar aqui